# How can I smooth a surface in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, surface

I have a surface in matlab which is plotted using the following code:

```
[xi, yi] = meshgrid(S/K, days);
vq = griddata(S/K, days, rbf/K, xi, yi,'natural');
mesh(xi,yi,vq)
```

The resulting image is quite rough, and has lots of grid lines as there are roughly 200 data points in each vector. Is it possible to plot a mesh which has a smaller number of grid points (e.g. 20) which averages out an existing meshgrid, griddata surface?

Comment: Without averaging: 

`mesh(xi(1:20:end,1:20,end),yi(1:20:end,1:20,end),vq(1:20:end,1:20,end))`

Comment: That solution does work well, but is there an easy way to average those points to produce a smoother surface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use `conv2` on your `vq` data to smooth, then downsample as @Ander suggested:

```
n = 5; % averaging size
vq_2 = conv2(vq, ones(n)/n.^2,'same');
mesh(xi(1:20:end,1:20,end),yi(1:20:end,1:20,end),vq_2(1:20:end,1:20,end))
```

There will be a bit of an edge effect as by default `conv2` pads with zeros.